# conflict with animete scrollTop and scrollHeight

Tags: jquery-animate, attr, scrolltop

I need help to use scrollHeight in this function:

```
    $('header').find('a').click(function(){
    hash = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top-74}, 1000, function(){
        //document.location.hash = hash;
    });
    return false;
});
```

When I put the attr scrollHeight, the function animate doesn't work.